# ford transit with suspension debonding issues

Tags: ford, suspension, transit

I put a deposit down for a van without checking its mot history. It turns out the last mot had an advisory on it. It said "nearside front suspension arm back bush starting to unbond"

1. What does that actually mean
2. Can I fix it myself?

I have put bikes together before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you have to fit a new bush.

Removing and replacing the old bush is relatively easy if you have a press and have taken the arm off.

An "old" way is to cut the bush out (hacksaw and chisel...) and make some "puller" to draw the new one in...